# Thread game loop causing problem with ArrayList

Tags: java, android, loops, arraylist

This is my 1st question on StackOverflow. I'm not a native English speaker so sorry for any mistakes.

FACTS:
I'm making 2D game in Android studio using Java. I'm using `SurfaceView`, abstract class `GameObject` and `ArrayList<GameObject>`. To loop through ArrayList I'm mostly using for-each loop - `for(GameObject obj: ArrayList)`. As a game loop I was using simple 60 fps game loop, but my computer emulator could reach max about 35 fps only.

PROBLEMS:
I have been working on this for couple of month and now i decided to use better game loop to have fixed update per second speed, so it will run the same speed on emulator and on devices. As soon as I try to `update()` more frequently then `draw()`, game started crashing on `for(GameObject obj: ArrayList)`.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
>       Process: com.janomat.helicosquares, PID: 27202
>       java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>           at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
>           at com.janomat.helicosquares.GameView.update(GameView.java:536)
>           at com.janomat.helicosquares.GameThread.run(GameThread.java:155)

Long time ago when I was learning to code in Java I found out that using for-each loop through ArrayList can make a problem if I need to remove obj. So I changed for-each loop for classic `for(int a=1; a < ArrayList.size; a++)` but then it stops rendering objects from array list. It looks like the objects are on screen invisible. I tried few game loops, even I made one but still the same.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you are still deleting items when looping through the list. Use a Iterator and then remove the items from list.

Comment: pls share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you are deleting items from list while looping through the list. One probable solution could be storing the items you want to remove in another list. Then you can remove the items from your original list using "list.removeAll(toberemovedItems)" method.

Or you can use the remove() method on the iterator itself. But in that case you have to loop through using an iterator and then you can call "iterator.remove()" method.

Hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank a lot. I forgot/didn't know about iterator. Because I dynamicly adding and removing object in array list i have to use ListIterator and it work nice now.

Comment: Btw. Any idea how it is possible that it was working before?